# When to use "am not" and "do not" in a sentence

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, negation, do-support

> "***I don't*** know what I'd do without you"
>
> "***I'm not*** know what I'd do without you"

Are these sentences correct?

What are the rules to use "not" in a sentence?

To what is ***not*** pointing in the above sentences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are negating with *not*, look at the finite verb in the clause, the one that carries person and tense.

- If it is an auxiliary verb (the first verb in a verbal construction) or a form of *be*, you may simply add *not*:

  > He is here. ... *The verb is a form of **be***. >>> He is not here.
  >   He has arrived. ... *The verb **has** is an auxiliary*. >>> He has not arrived.
  >   He must have arrived. ... *The verb **must** is an auxiliary*. >>> He must not have arrived.
- Otherwise, you require *DO-support*:

  > He came today. ... *The verb **came** is not an auxiliary*. >>> He did not come today.
  >   He arrived today. ... *The verb **arrived** is not an auxiliary*. >>> He did not arrive today.
  >   He has a car. ... *Here **has** is not an auxiliary but a lexical verb meaning 'possesses'*. >>> He does not have a car.

Until the twentieth century it was common to negate lexical *HAVE* without *DO-support*, but this is disappearing. Even earlier **any** verb might be negated without *DO-support*, but that died out by the nineteenth century.

Comment: At one time it was also common to negate the main verb without including do-support, but ["I know not what to say"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I+know+not+what+to+say%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) has a decidedly "Shakespearean" flavour today.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Quite. I'll add that.

Comment: Other constuctions add: *can, need* and son on.

Comment: @Ale : *Can/could, may/might, shall/should, will/would*, like *must*, *have* and *be* are auxiliaries.

Comment: Of course, I know, I thought you were going to put them all.

Comment: @Ale I see no need to expand this indefinitely; most folks who need answers to questions like this know what auxiliaries are.

Answer (score 1):

"I don't know " is correct. It is the negative of "I know". Other examples:

I like it. (positive) - I do not like it. (negative)

I watch TV. (positive) - I do not watch TV. (negative)

"I'm not know" is wrong. If you try to say the negative of "I know", that is "I don't know". If you want to use "I am not", it is the negative of "I am". For example"

I am from France.(positive) - I am not from France (negative)

I am tired. (positive) -  I am not tired. (negative)

I am cooking. (positive) - I am not cooking. (negative)

Answer (score 1):

The constructions you are looking at are different and represent important structures in English.

"I do X" where X is a verb is an example of [do-support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support). Technically, you don't need to use do-support in positive statements, e.g. "I do know". When do-support is used with positive statements then *do* acts to emphasise the claim. E.g.

> A: Do you know your twelve times table?
>   B: Yes, I know it.
>   A: I bet you're lying to sound clever.
>   B: I am not! **I do know it!**

In the above example the *do* is used as emphasis by B.

In negative situations, *do* is used as an auxillary (or helper) verb when denying something, e.g. "I do not know." This is because *"I not know" is not grammatical.

Do-support is only used with the infinitive, i.e. the form of verb that matches its name.

So you say

- "I do not know", never *"I do not knowing".
- "He does not know", never *"He does not knows".

In these situations *not* is pointing to the verb being supported by *do*. I.e. *not* is negating the verb.

Your other construction: "I am X", where X is a verb. Here *am* is also a helper verb. *Am* is a form of the verb *be*. Using *be* in this way is using it as a [copular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_%28linguistics%29#English) verb. That means it is joining something to something else. For example in "I am happy" *am* is joining the subject *I* to the adjective (descriptive word) *happy*. The same is happening in "He is cold", *he* is the subject and *cold* is the adjective it is being joined to.

When used with a verb, *be* joins the subject to the finite forms of the verb (finite meaning the forms that change based on who is the subject and whether you're talking about past, present, future, etc.). For example: "I am writing an answer". This uses *be* to create the present progressive form of *write*.

When creating a negative statement about your actions, then you use the same form of the verb, e.g. "I am **not** writing an answer".

In this example *not* is pointing to *writing*.

Back to your examples: *"I am not know" is wrong because *know* is the infinitive form, and *am* must work with a finite form. However, because of the type of verb that *know* is, saying *"I am not knowing" is **also** wrong. This is complicated to explain and I can't think of other verbs that behave like this right now.

As a rule of thumb, when making statements about what you or others do not know, use *do*, never use *be*.

Answer (score 0):

I get that what you are trying to write is the negation of "I know" in "I know what I'd do without you."

Using the simple present, the negation of a verb that is not *be*, used in a sentence that is not a question, is done by adding "don't" or "doesn't" (the latter is for the third person singular) between the subject, and the verb. In your case, the sentence becomes:

> I don't know what I'd do without you.